# STEP 2 1990 Question 4: Proving Conditional Perpendicularity of points in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

I have been doing some STEP past papers for fun and I stumbled on a problem that is giving me trouble. The question is linked here   [image: Question]

I am completely stuck as I don't have an idea how to approach the first part. I drew the diagram and I recognized the cyclic quadrilateral inside the circle, however, I am not sure how to use the perpendicular bisectors of the chords. I know that a perpendicular bisector to a chord has a direction towards the centre but I don't know how this could be used to solve the problem. If anybody could suggest an intuitive way of thinking about it and using the information given in the question I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 chords are perpendicular if and only if their perpendicular bisectors are also perpendicular.

It's much easier to deal with their perpendicular bisectors esp since you know that they intersect at the center (which is the origin), then it is to find the intersection of $LM$ and $PQ$.

What is the equation for the perpendicular bisectors (or at least, the directional vector)?
What does it mean for these 2 lines to be perpendicular?

Comment: Hi @Calvin Lin , thanks for the response. For the direction of the bisectors is it $\frac{-1}{\overrightarrow{PQ}}$ and $\frac{-1}{\overrightarrow{LM}}$ for PQ's and LM's respective bisectors? Then do we just set up the argument for their perpendicularity giving $\overrightarrow{PQ}=\overrightarrow{LM}$? I also wanted to ask, if my logic is true why does $l \times m$ corespond to the direction of the vector $\overrightarrow{LM}$ and similarly why does $p \times q$ corespond tothe direction of the vector $\overrightarrow{PQ}$?

Comment: It's a complex numbers question right? So use that language instead. Note that $\frac{-1}{\vec{PQ}}$ makes very little sense notationally. What's the multiplicity inverse of a vector? You seem to be mixing up concepts in coordinate geometry with vectors here.

Comment: Sorry by $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ I meant the direction of it. So using that that notation $\overrightarrow{PQ}$  becomes $q-p$ and $\overrightarrow{LM}$  becomes $m-l$ but I need to get $q\times p$ and $l\times m$. Is this wrong and if not why does it differ from what the question requires?

Comment: Again, you seem to be mixing up concepts. The direction for the multiplicative inverse of the complex number is reflection about the x-axis, multiplication by -1 is a $180^\circ$ rotation. How does this lead to a perpendicular line? Once you figured out what the actual version should be, think about 1) How to relate it to $pq, lm$ and 2) Recall which condition you haven't used yet.